# Throwing and Catching Custom Exceptions

Tags: c++, exception

I need to add one or more try blocks and accompanying catch handlers to my main program. The catch handlers will catch the exceptions thrown by the overloaded extraction operator of my class.

I implemented the overloaded extraction operator to throw a new exception however the catch blocks in my main program appear to be not working/catching those exceptions.

Here's a code sample from my main program.

```
cout << "\nEnter 2 Complex numbers in the form \"(real_value,imaginary_value)\" :\n";

try
{
    cin >> A >> B;
}
catch (Invalid_Mode1_Complex_Value_Exception& exception)
{
    cout << "Exception occured: " << exception.what() << endl;
    newFormat = cin.flags();  //find out how flags are set now
    cout << "\nThe cin format flags are set to: " << newFormat << endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong? Any advice or help would be appreciated. Thanks. Here's the code for throwing the exception.

```
// overloads the binary ">>" operator through a global friend function
istream & operator >> (istream & input, Complex & obj)
{
    // First check if the failbit is already set
    if (input.fail())
    {
        return input;  //if so, go home
    }
    ios_base::fmtflags origFormat;  // Create format flag
    origFormat = input.flags();  // save original flag setting

    // Process '('
    input.ignore(2, '('); // skip over '('

    // Process real part
    input >> obj.real_part; // read the real component of the Complex #

    // Process ','
    if (input.peek() == ',')
    {
        input.get(); // swallow ','
    }
    else // we have a problem
    {
        throw new Invalid_Mode1_Complex_Value_Exception(); // throw new exception
        input.clear();

        // restore format flags
        input.flags(origFormat);

        return input;
    }

    // Process imaginary part

    // read the imaginary component of the Complex #
    input >> obj.imaginary_part;

    // Process ')'
    if (input.peek() == ')')
    {
        input.get(); // swallow ')'
    }
    else // we have a problem
    {
        throw new Invalid_Mode1_Complex_Value_Exception(); // throw new exception
        input.clear(); 

        // restore format flags
        input.flags(origFormat);

        return input;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). At the very least, how are you `throw`ing?

Comment: Hi Barry. Sorry about the confusion. Just edited my post. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need in operator `new`, so you `throw` statement

```
throw new Invalid_Mode1_Complex_Value_Exception();
```

should be

```
throw Invalid_Mode1_Complex_Value_Exception();
```

or you need to catch pointer (however this is worse, since you need to check if it is `nullptr`)

```
catch(Invalid_Mode1_Complex_Value_Exception* exception) {
    ....
}
```

References and pointers are different types, so you can't throw one and catch another. Take a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)#C_and_C.2B.2B) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)).

Comment: Thanks! I tried your method and made some other change and it works now.